# Plotting of Principal Component Analysis Results in R

Tags: r, plot

On youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xKl4LJAXnEA) i stumbled on this plot (see below). This guy performed PCA analysis and came up with a very nice way to plot his results. It seems that his y-variable was categorical.

However mine is numeric. Are there any similar ideas to plot my results in a decent way? I'd love to see groupings. thanks in advance!

The plot;
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen a similar plot on http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/31-principal-component-methods-in-r-practical-guide/112-pca-principal-component-analysis-essentials/

It may be useful !

```
iris.pca <- PCA(iris [, - 5], graph = FALSE)

fviz_pca_ind(iris.pca,
         geom.ind = "point", # Montre les points seulement (mais pas le "text")
         col.ind = iris$Species, # colorer by groups
         palette = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800", "#FC4E07"),
         addEllipses = TRUE, # Ellipses de concentration
         legend.title = "Groups"
         )
```

Comment: I got it working, but still not able to produce these fancy cluster plots with continous variables, but i think it's not possible at all. This is the best i can get with continous variables. thanks for the tip!